# Terraform - Cloudwatch alarm Elasticache cluster metrics

Tags: amazon-elasticache, terraform-provider-aws

Can someone suggest on how we can create alarms for Elasticache cluster for "CPUUtilization" and "FreeableMemory" using Terraform?

Elasticache seems like an exception where we are unable to get cluster level metrics. Seems like current workaround is to create alarms at node level.

Haven't tried below but seems like a workaround -
https://github.com/azavea/terraform-aws-redis-elasticache/blob/develop/main.tf

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CloudWatchMetrics.html).

Answer (score -1):

Here is my terraform module to create cloudwatch alerts for rds and cache clusters at node level.

https://bitbucket.org/rkkrishnaa/terraform/src/master/

I have added Jenkinsfile to deploy the alerts through CI.